# iOS auto updates

Tags: ios, cordova, appstore-approval, auto-update

It takes 10 days to submit update and wait it to be reviewed.
One of my farm games I that I installed on iPad shows "downloading updates" when I run it.

- Is it good idea to implement updates in iOS app like that?
- Is it permitted by Apple?
- Do you know apps doing that except farm apps?

I am thinking about PhoneGap. I could download new version of phonegap extract it and run.

So I will add features directly dially or even push different functionality to different clients.
It is also a way to overcome encryption restrictions.

Right now it is not clear if HTML code that has https link, recourses has to be certified for export from US.

App may download HTML/JS code from EU server to overcome US export restrictions.

Comment: I have seen magazine Apps that download massive amount of new contents previously!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it good idea to implement updates in iOS app like that?

It would be certainly a good idea, but it is forbidden. However, you can download some content which is not actually an executable.

> Is it permitted by Apple?

It is not. You cannot download any form of code or binary and run it on devices. I would give you some reference but it would violate NDA between Apple and Developers. Please check your agreement with Apple.

> Do you know apps doing that except farm apps?

They download content, but not sure about the binaries which add functionality.

In the scenario of using Phonegap, you can download HTML/JS files which are not meant to be executables. But due the nature of Phonegap, you can use those files to execute code. Therefore, IMHO, I suspect that you will not pass the App review.

Additionally you will need to download those files into your `www` folder. Even, **writing** outside of `documents` folder in run time is not allowed, as far as I know. I have my app rejected just because of this.

Comment: [/Library/Caches is more suitable in my case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209406/ios-5-does-not-allow-to-store-downloaded-data-in-documents-directory). Also PhoneGap has [wwwFolderName](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html). I understand: if I ask Apple if I am permitted to update app they will tell NO. But after I saw that farm app was telling me. "Please wait, downloading updates". I started thinking that I do too much self control.

Comment: +1 Oh yes, as you said there might be some possible work around available for downloaded content for Phonegap. But in the end, I think they will not accept this architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as I see you could do it through the In-App Purchase API, couldn't you?

I took it from iOS Developer Program License Agreement

> 1.1   You may use the In-App Purchase API only to enable end-users to access or receive content, functionality, or services that You make available for use within Your Application (e.g., digital books, additional game levels, access to a turn-by-turn map service). You may not use the In-App Purchase API to offer goods or services to be used outside of Your Application.

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer, and I was also confused by the term "You cannot download any form of code or binary and run it on devices", but it turns out my app passed the review several times without a single rejection. And it's not even a PhoneGap app, it's just a web app online with offline cache.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, help a lot